# Bootstrap 4 dropdown menus to start from the first menu position

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I would like the dropdown menus to start from the position where the first dropdown starts. There are several dropdown menus. See screen for example.

**JSFiddel:** https://jsfiddle.net/kfh9Lbep/

[image]

How do I go about this?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo!</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav position-static">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Dropdown 1
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu w-100">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Dropdown 2
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu w-100">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>  
    </div>  
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo!</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav position-static">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Dropdown 1
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu w-100">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Dropdown 2
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu w-100 left-taken">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>  
    </div>  
  </div>  
</div>
```

css:

```css
.left-taken {
  left: -7.5rem;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work when I have to add another menu: Dropdown 3, Dropdown 4, Dropdown 5 etc.